# Ajax call on Elementor WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am currently developing a widget for elementor and i have already done the PHP render part as it renders the HTML part dynamically. Now, i want to do same for js render part as live rendering. I thought of Ajax call so that I can get data from it and place it on js render part. I tried to Ajax call inside _content_template() function but it load first instead of HTML while adding it to the post while PHP render is fine. How can i handle this. Please any help is appreciated.